# Apache Pig how to enforce a schema on a relation

Tags: apache-pig

I need to perform a filter operation in Pig.  There are two relations 'a' and 'b'.  Each has an ID and a timestamp, as well as many other fields.  I want to return a version of 'a' where every row with a certain time difference from 'b' is removed.  Rows in both relations are unordered but matched based on an ID.

The problem is that after the operation, I'm stuck with a relation with a bunch of fields from 'b'.  The only method I've seen of removing columns is the FOREACH statement below, but the actual relations have a large number of elements and makes the code huge, hard to maintain, and buggy.

```
a = LOAD 'a.txt' AS (a1:chararray, aTime:chararray, aId:chararray);
b = LOAD 'b.txt' AS (b1:chararray, bTime:chararray, bId:chararray);

--Match a and b rows together based on similar ID's
ab = JOIN a BY aId LEFT OUTER, b BY bId;

--Remove rows with a big difference in timestamps
ab = FILTER ab BY timeDifference(a::aTime, b::bTime) < 60;

--ab has columns from b left over, I only want columns from relation a
aResult = FOREACH ab GENERATE
    a1 AS a1,
    aTime AS aTime,
    aId AS aId; --This list is way too awkward
```

Is there a better way to do this sort of operation in Pig, removing rows in a relation based on the columns in a different relation?

Comment: May be something like, aResult = FOREACH ab generate $0..$n; where n is number of columns in 'a' less 1. Just experiment with this method to find the right number.

Comment: is aID unique in dataset?